# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME (localhost vs domain)

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I am running my php code in docker with Nginx and fastcgi

I am exposing port 9999 of my docker container

So to invoke my application I do: 
http://localhost:9999/index.php

I also have a localdomain: **example.com** which is pointing to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts.
So I can invoke my application using example.com:9999/index.php

Strange thing I noticed is, when I use localhost url, I am getting an error on my browser

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "http://localhost:9999/css/login.css?v=1".
```

I don't get the above error if I inovke it using example.com

Can somebody explain why is the strange behavior happening?

The nginx config is as follows:

```
events {
    multi_accept on;
    worker_connections 65535;
}


http {

    # MIME
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    # logging
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

    server {

        listen       80  default_server;
        server_name  _;

        index index.php;
        root /code/Public;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php {

            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

        }
    }

}
```

This is my Dockerfile config:

```
FROM phpdockerio/php73-fpm

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y php7.3-memcache
RUN apt-get install -y php7.3-curl

RUN apt-get install -y nginx

ADD docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

CMD ["sh", "-c", "service nginx restart ; /usr/sbin/php-fpm7.3 -O"]
```

FYI: I am using slim-framework. here is the reference [doc](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/start/web-servers.html) for setting up nginx

Comment: What is the content type for each of the css urls ? (i.e. `curl -I <css-url> | grep ^content-type`).

Comment: Content-Type: text/html

Comment: I just realized that it is not throwing the Resource interpreted error anymore. (even on localhost url) Could this be some caching issue?

Comment: Without being able to reproduce it, we will probably never know.